# Understanding CloudSQL monitoring charts

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble understanding what these graphs from the monitoring page of the CloudSQL console are trying to show...

For the first graph, the view criteria (shown in the graph title) are "time range = 1 day, interval size = 15 minutes."  But... what am I seeing here?  Why are the bars are like ~2.5 hours apart?  And why are there big gaps in between them? (no, our app doesn't have a bizarre access pattern)

The second graph is the same, but with "interval size = 1 hour" - if you look closely all that has changed is the bars got fatter.  They are still ~2.5 hours apart and still have gaps in between them.

I'm a little confused...

[image: cloudsql charts]

Comment: Hi Ian. The reason you are seeing this is because that the minimum granularity of that data seems to be about 2 hours. So it looks like every 2 hours there was a peak instead with the total value instead of the operations spread over time. This should be fixed soon and you will see averaged per second rates instead of counts.

Comment: Hi Juan - Great to hear that this is being looked at and will be fixed soon.  I don't suppose there is a bug being tracked somewhere that I can follow?

Comment: Not really. I'll post here once it is fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ian, the Cloud SQL instance page has been updated with the new monitoring charts showing per second rates. Thanks for your feedback.